# Base64 encode using boost throw exception

Tags: c++, string, boost, iterator, base64

I trying to use boost base64 encoder, I found an example but I got and exception

```
typedef 
transform_width< binary_from_base64<std::string::const_iterator>, 8, 6 > it_binary_t
```

an I used

```
std::string b64E(it_binary_t(Encrip.begin()), it_binary_t(Encrip.end()));
```

I get it

> Unhandled exception at 0x75b1b9bc in agentid_coder.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: boost::archive::iterators::dataflow_exception at memory
>   location 0x0046ed94..

I found this workaround but I get the same result

```
 string dec( 
        it_binary_t(Encrip.begin()), 
        it_binary_t(Encrip.begin() + Encrip.length() - 1) 
        );
```

I am using MSVS2008 and boost 1.38

Comment: Base64 encoding functions using Boost C++ Library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680998/attempt-to-decode-a-value-not-in-base64-char-set

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Unfortunately the combination of the two `iterator_adaptors` `binary_from_base64` and `transform_width` is not a complete base64 encoder/decoder. Base64 represents groups of 24 bits (3 bytes) as 4 characters, each of which encodes 6 bits. If the input data is not an integer multiple of such 3 byte groups it has to be padded with one or two zero bytes. To indicate how many padding bytes were added, one or two `=` characters are appended to the encoded string.

`transform_width`, which is responsible for the 8bit binary to 6bit integer conversion does not apply this padding automatically, it has do be done by the user. A simple example:

```
#include <boost/archive/iterators/base64_from_binary.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/binary_from_base64.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/transform_width.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/insert_linebreaks.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/remove_whitespace.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::archive::iterators;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  typedef transform_width< binary_from_base64<remove_whitespace<string::const_iterator> >, 8, 6 > it_binary_t;
  typedef insert_linebreaks<base64_from_binary<transform_width<string::const_iterator,6,8> >, 72 > it_base64_t;
  string s;
  getline(cin, s, '\n');
  cout << "Your string is: '"<<s<<"'"<<endl;

  // Encode
  unsigned int writePaddChars = (3-s.length()%3)%3;
  string base64(it_base64_t(s.begin()),it_base64_t(s.end()));
  base64.append(writePaddChars,'=');

  cout << "Base64 representation: " << base64 << endl;

  // Decode
  unsigned int paddChars = count(base64.begin(), base64.end(), '=');
  std::replace(base64.begin(),base64.end(),'=','A'); // replace '=' by base64 encoding of '\0'
  string result(it_binary_t(base64.begin()), it_binary_t(base64.end())); // decode
  result.erase(result.end()-paddChars,result.end());  // erase padding '\0' characters
  cout << "Decoded: " << result << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Note that I added the `insert_linebreaks` and `remove_whitespace` iterators, so that the base64 output is nicely formatted and base64 input with line breaks can be decoded. These are optional though.

Run with different input strings which require different padding:

```
$ ./base64example
Hello World!
Your string is: 'Hello World!'
Base64 representation: SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh
Decoded: Hello World!
$ ./base64example
Hello World!!
Your string is: 'Hello World!!'
Base64 representation: SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhIQ==
Decoded: Hello World!!
$ ./base64example
Hello World!!!
Your string is: 'Hello World!!!'
Base64 representation: SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhISE=
Decoded: Hello World!!!
```

You can check the base64 strings with this [online-encoder/decoder](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp).

Comment: Well done for adding a full encode/decode implementation!  The lack of padding caught me out too.

Comment: can you explain why you need second %3 in (3-s.length()%3)%3

Comment: We need a result in {0,1,2}. Without the second %3 we get a result in {1,2,3}. The last %3 maps the result 3 to 0 and leaves 1 and 2 alone. Another possibility would be something like s.length()%3?3-s.length()%3:0

Comment: Doh. :) btw this crashes(deep in the boost) when I have spaces at the end of the input string... Is that expected?

Comment: No, that is definitely not expected, and it works fine for me also with spaces at the end of the input string (boost-1.49.0). Or did you mean spaces at the end of the *encoded* string?

Comment: no , just input string has spaces at the end... BTW it crashes because of VS2010 Debug assertions and Im on boost 1-44 so unfortunately I see no way I can give you more info because like I said it doesnt crash crash, some debug assertion fails and it is in boost code that is undecodable by mere mortals. :D

Comment: How could I check if we have a valid base64 string as input?

Comment: @PiQuer Is there any reason why I couldn't do something similar to encode a hexadecimal string in base64? I modified it to this: `insert_linebreaks<base64_from_binary<transform_width<string::const_iterator,6, 4>>, 64> it_base64_t;` and it almost works, but some of the base64 characters are encoded wrong?