# What can I use instead of <gloox/inbandbytestreammanager.h>, because it was removed in gloox 1.0

Tags: c++, file-transfer, gloox

I need to send binary data encoded by base64. I'm using C++ gloox library, so I can use  `#include <gloox/base64.h>` fo encoding. First I was going to use `<gloox/inbandbytestreammanager.h>` for sending and receiving data, but now it turn out to be removed in gloox. What can I use instead of it and how can I do it. I need to send binary data and receive it using something like data handler and activate DataHanler with registerDataHandler.  Can anybody help to find examples how and with what to do it, please.  I really need it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose you could [use Boost][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053538/how-do-i-encode-a-string-to-base64-using-only-boost

Comment: @Pukku I need to use gloox library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functionality of the class InBandBytestreamManager has been merged with SI-based file transfer (SIProfileFT) in 1.0

You can use this class - http://camaya.net/api/gloox/classgloox_1_1SIProfileFT.html