# Unpacking a stream of values of bit size not divisible by 8

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I've spent too many hours on this, and at this point I think I need some help from the experts.

I have a `const uint8_t* buffer`, an integer data type (say, `uint16_t`), and I know that the `buffer` contains packed samples `m` bits each where `m` is not divisible by 8 (say, m=12 bits). Knowing that `buffer` holds `N` samples, I need to return an `std::vector<uint16_t>` containing the values of these `N` samples expanded to `uint16_t`.

So, each three bytes (24 bits) of the `buffer` contain two 12-bits samples I need to process. I want to implement a generalized function

```
template <typename OutputType, int BitsPerSample>
std::vector<OutputType> unpack(const uint8_t* data, const size_t numSamplesToUnpack);
```

Assume the data is big endian and `OutputType` is some integer type that can hold the sample value without truncating it.

I understand bit manipulation. I understand how this can be implemented, in principle. But I don't understand how to implement it elegantly and concisely. Got any ideas?

Also, is there a special name or term for this problem?

Comment: Did you check `boost::transform_width` ?

Comment: This could be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053538/how-do-i-encode-a-string-to-base64-using-only-boost

Comment: @Slava: not before you pointed it out (I don't have `boost` in this project, nor do I want to pull it in). That's... a lot of code. Kinda looks like what I would write naively, except it's even more generalized and abstracted.

Comment: Asking for "implement it elegantly and concisely. Got any ideas?" makes this "opinion-based". Also,first thing that cames to my mind is, "what have you tried"? If you've spent X hours,surely you have some moreorless broken pieces of code. Maybe show them and fix them here? Also,is your goal just to solve it,or to take the excercise and implement it yourself? Also, how complex do you want it to have? what OutputTypes do you want to support and how they can be constructed and/or filled? Also,is `data` BigEndian, LittleEndian? Far too many unknowns and it all impacts elegancy/verbosity..

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: I will expand the question. Note that while you're not wrong about it being opinion-based, I'm not asking for complete implementation, just for approaches I could try (but eventually I just need it to work, it's not an exercise, it's a real-world problem).

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: as for what I have tried - nothing I finished because it's becoming too many lines of code too quickly, and I've already spent ungodly amount of time without even getting a debuggable implementation. I strongly suspect there are simpler ways than the one I saw.

Comment: Depending on your actual requirements, `numberOfSamplesToUnpack` may be a run-time, not compile-time decision.

Comment: @Arkadiy: fair enough, that's an unnecessary restriction, let me edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try reading single bits at a time, and keep a running counter of how many bits you have processed. When you consume 8 bits, you can increment your buffer pointer.

This doesn't mean you have finished unpacking that sample, so you'll need to also keep a "bits_left" counter in case you need to shift the buffer pointer before you are done unpacking a sample.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't consider literally reading single bits rather than chunks.

Comment: I mean, for the sake of speed, you can optimize it to actually read in chunks, but then you need to make sure you deal with remainder bits left over. (say a 9 bit sample, you can read in a byte followed by 1 bit). This might not be possible if the sample size is smaller than a byte, so...

Answer (score 0):

Use a 32-bit word as a buffer. If it has less than 12 bits, read another byte. Otherwise, output a 12-bit word.