# Base64 decode in InstallScript installer

Tags: base64, windows-installer, installscript-msi

I have one InstallScript installer. In this installer, I wanted to encode and decode one string using base64 encoding/decoding. Is there any function or API available in InstallScript to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Too little time to really answer, but how about throwing in some suggestions anyway? (too long to make it a comment):

- I suppose you could look into the [**Boost C++ library**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48176443/129130)? (Should be callable from Installscript? I haven't worked with Installscript properly for a long time).
- Also, over at [**installsite.org**](http://installsite.org/) you could check with the community: [**forum.installsite.net**](http://forum.installsite.net) for any further clues? I couldn't find anything in the Installscript samples list, but have a look there too? (link from front page). I bet Stefan Kruger himself would certainly know how to do this.
- There is also the Installshield community: [**community.installshield.com**](http://community.installshield.com). I would check specifically if the use of Boost is something that is not desirable - for some reason I am unware of (for example better features in Installshield that I don't know about).